# LLVM lit testing: is it possible to configure number of threads via `lit.cfg`?

Tags: testing, llvm

I wonder if it's possible to configure the number of threads for testing in a `lit.cfg` file.

`lit` offers a command-line flag for specifying the number of threads:

`llvm/utils/lit/lit.py -j1 <test directory>`

However, I'm not sure how to do this in a `lit.cfg` file. I want to force all tests in a subdirectory to be run with `-j1` - not sure if this is possible.

Edit: for reference, I'm working on the [Swift codebase](https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/master/test) which has a large test suite (4000+ tests) with multiple test subdirectories.
I want to run just one subdirectory with `-j1` and the rest with the default number of threads (`-j12` for my machine).

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about that too a while back, but I don't think there is one because of this line [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/a9de7e5e9c7226a33c046d0b438728ba1f6010f0/utils/lit/lit/main.py#L339). Usually, the main project compilation times dwarf the `lit` tests execution time.

It is easy to change, but I'd suggest using your build configuration to this (e.g. `make` or `cmake`). So, `make test` could execute something like `lit -j $(nproc)` underneath.

**Edit** (after OP update):

I haven't worked with the `swift` repo, but maybe you could hack your way around. One thing I could see is that you could influence the `LIT_ARGS` `cmake` [variable](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/0fcaef1276ec97254386a844b9143a0a511b3228/test/CMakeLists.txt#L266) with the options you want by appending to it.

Now to force a single process execution for a specific directory, you may add a `lit.local.cfg` that sets the [singleProcess](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/utils/lit/lit/LitConfig.py) flag. This seems to override multi-thread execution:

```
config.singleProcess = True
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I added some more contextual information to the OP. I'm looking for a way to configure # of threads for a specific test subdirectory. Not sure how to do that cleanly with `nproc`.